# why i can't call name from table food?

Tags: laravel-5

public function orderlist(Request $request){
        $id = $request->id;

```
    $data['order'] = Order::where('shop_id',$id)->orderBy('id')->get();
            foreach($data['order'] as $orders){
                $orders->shop = Shop::where('id',$orders->shop_id)->first();
                $orders->food = Food::where('id',$orders->food_id)->get();
            }   
            return $orders->food->name;
    return view ('administrator.users.list_order.index',$data);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest explaining your problem in more detail and edit your question to show the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up proper Eloquent relationships, this code could be rewritten like so:

```
public function orderlist(Request $request, Shop $shop){
    $orders = $shop->orders()->with(['food'])->get();
    return view ('administrator.users.list_order.index',compact('orders'));
}
```

Check out the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships